# Load X number of images with img width based on window size

Tags: jquery, math, width, equation

I honestly don't know where to start on this one. But I got the idea in my head, and I would very much like to see if it's possible to execute.

I'm using [Instagram jQuery plugin](https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram) to load instagram images based on a hashtag. What I would like to achieve (or rather, have someone help me achieve) is to set the number of images to load AND their width depending on the window size.

ex. 1 if window is 1200px wide, load 12 picture with a width of 100px on each image
ex. 2 if window is 800px wide, load 10 pictures with a width of 80px on each image
etc...

But this has to be done dynamically so that the number of images and their width always correspond to a total of the windows width. This is for one, to make sure that there is only one row of images (without the use of "overflow hidden" etc).

Here is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var insta_container = $(".instaflow"), insta_next_url

insta_container.instagram({
    hash: 'ASuperAwesomeHashTag',
    clientId : 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    show : 16,
    onComplete : function (photos, data) {
        insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url
        var instaimg = $('img.instagram-image');
        instaimg.css({ 'width': ($(window).width()/1) });
    }
})

$('button').on('click', function(){
var button = $(this), text = button.text()

    if (button.text() != 'LOADING' && button.hasClass('icon-plus-sign-alt')){
        button.removeClass('icon-plus-sign-alt')
        button.addClass('loading')
        button.text('LOADING')
        insta_container.instagram({
            next_url : insta_next_url,
            show : 8,
            onComplete : function(photos, data) {
                if ($('.instagram-placeholder').children().text() != ""){
                    button.remove();
                }
                insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url
                button.text(text)
                button.removeClass('loading')
                button.addClass('icon-plus-sign-alt')
            }
        })
    }
})
});
```

So, the "show" value has to be relativ to how much width there is to utilize. Loading 20 photos in a window that is only 600px wide won't look nice. + I want to make sure that there is only ONE row of images (without using overflow hidden on DIVs etc. Since there is a load more button, it wouldn't show the "more pictures if they are "trapped" in a DIV that "cuts of"). That's why I also need to define the width based on the number of images with the width of the window.

I understand that this might be a"diffuse" question. But if anybody feels they can help me in getting this done I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always leave the images with dimensions of 100px each

```
var img_amount = $(window).width()/100;
//in this case each image dimension will be 100px
var img_dimension = $(window).width()/img_amount; 
//if you want to go for a cross browser solution and not use the css property 'box-sizing'
//subtract the padding and margins of the images (if any)
img_dimension -= [padding + margin];
//subtract any borders
img_dimension -= [border width];
```

Now if you want to have as many pictures as possible without making the distorting the page layout you could do something like this:

```
var reduced_dimension = $(window).width()/100;
var min_amount = 6;
var img_amount = min_amount + parseInt(reduced_dimension/2);
```

and this way if the window width is 800px, then `img_amoung = 6 + parseInt(8/2)` which will be 10

to determine the number of images based on a minimum image width and and minimum image height you could do this:

```
function determineAmount(width, divisor){
    var reduced_dimension = width/divisor;
    var min_dimension = 50; //minimum 50px
    var max_dimension = 250; //maximum 250px
    var min_amount = 6;
    //start calculations
    var img_amount = min_amount + parseInt(reduced_dimension/2);
    var img_dimension = width/img_amount;
    if(img_dimension < min_dimension){
       return determineAmount(width, divisor + 10);
    }
    else if(img_dimension > max_dimension){
       return determineAmount(width, divisor - 10);
    }

    return {'amount':img_amount,'dimension':img_dimension};
}
```

And you would call it like so: `determineAmount($(window).width(), 100)` 
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jwhrQ/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it doesn't really address the concern of getting an appropriate number value to enter in the "show" option. This number has to be defined by the number of images that will fit in one row depending on the size of the window. Then define the image width value accordingly.

Comment: Hmm... getting there. I changed the var reduced_dimension = $(window).width()/100; to var reduced_dimension = $(window).width()/$(window).width(); So now it loads X images and fills the width. But this is still based on a fixed number (min_amount 6). What I'm trying to accomplish is to make the number of images shown based on a min width value for the images. So lets say an image shouldn't be less than 100px wide, then, according to that number, decide how many images can fit in the width. Then, if necessary, increase the width so the images strech all the way.

Comment: In other words, completely dynamic with only a min and (realizing as I go along here) max value for the image width.  :)

Comment: wouldn't $(window).width()/$(window).width() always be 1?

Comment: That is correct. could just as well change that var. Nevertheless, this would not be a fully dynamic solution dependent on a min and max width value for the images  :D

Comment: I'm just learning Jquery now, so I was just trying out all sorts of combinations and that one worked (just didn't change it)... however, I can do math (divide), so yes, I was aware that the result was 1  haha  :)  just thought you should know, new to jquery and these types of solutions. I did however manage to finish grade school though ;)  Thanks again for all your effort!

Comment: I just updated the answer. Something to note is that that is probably a really bad example of a function, but the logic is there. Check for the values and if they are not what you want, then call the function again

Comment: wow, that looks like a working solution :) thank you... however, I have no idea how to implement it in the existing code haha  Where/how do I call the function? I tried replacing
instaimg.css({ 'width': ($(window).width()/1) });
with
instaimg.css({ 'width': (determineAmount($(window).width(), 100)) });
but that yields nothing. It was just a longshot. Not really sure how to "call" a function and when it should be done. Why would this be a bad example of a function?

Comment: Do this: $(document).ready(function(){var values = determineAmount( $(window).width(), 100, 1)});var amount = values['amount']; var dimension = values['dimension']; ....

Comment: ... insta_container.instagram({
    hash: 'ASuperAwesomeHashTag',
    clientId : 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    show : amount,
    onComplete : function (photos, data) {
        insta_next_url = data.pagination.next_url
        var instaimg = $('img.instagram-image');
        instaimg.css({ 'width': dimension+'px' });
    }
})//close document.ready });

Comment: I can't really get it to work... but that fault lies with me. I believe I have to learn a little bit more about JavaScript and Jquery. Think I bit of a little more than I could chew  haha... However, when I do feel more "at home" with javascript, Jquery and functions I will revisit this. Thank you for your time and effort @lomas09